# A direct proof that a compact metric space is sequentially compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I am looking for a direct proof (not by contradiction) that a compact metric space is sequentially compact, ie constructing a converging subsequence from any sequence.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $n$ cover the space $X$ by balls of radius $1/n$.  Choose finite subcovers for each $n$.  Then there is at least one set in each cover with infinitely many sequence elements.  Use this to create a subsequence which is Cauchy.

Comment: Thanks. In your last step "use this to create a subsequence which is Cauchy", do you need the axiom of choice to create it ? Actually this is precisely where I blocked in finding a proof.

Comment: Actually, no, because the sequence is countable.  Just choose the least indexed element which lies in the set and is indexed greater than all other chosen elements.

Comment: I'm not well versed in logic like this but I don't think you need the axiom of choice to choose something from a countable set, since they are basically well ordered by definition.

Comment: Thanks, but I still do not get a last detail. How to choose one particular set in the finite sub cover if there are more than one with infinitely many elements?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure if you need axiom to "choose" the finite subcover (whose existence is by definition of compactness).  Really, I wouldn't consider the proof is constructive, but it is definitely direct.

Comment: Once you have the finite subcover, you can choose one of the finitely many sets with infinitely many elements in them.  And once you have that set you can choose a sequence element since the sequence is countable.

Comment: You don't need axiom of choice to choose from a set that is well ordered, I believe.  So finite sets or countable sets, in this case.

Comment: Actually I did not mean choosing the sub cover but choosing one particular set in the sub cover: it may happen that more than one set in the sub cover has infinitely many sequence elements

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Thanks.

Comment: I'm wondering whether the same scheme of proof works to prove that in a compact space every net has a convergent subnet ...?

Comment: @Seth $\mathbb Q$ is countable and it isn't well ordered. Well ordering an arbitrary countable set can't be done in a finite number of steps. Just because a bijection with the integers exists doesn't mean you have access to a specific one.

Comment: @MattSamuel hmmm, ok, I don't have any background at all in this kind of formal set theoretic stuff.  Does it require the axiom of choice to "choose" a finite subcover, or is that part of the definition of compactness?

Comment: @Seth The definition of compactness is that a finite subcover exists. It provides no canonical method for choosing that subcover. As to whether the axiom of choice is required, that depends on the situation. I'm having trouble thinking of a killer example, though, so if you're really interested you may want to post it as a question and let the set theorists take a crack at it.

Comment: @MattSamuel Thanks, I agree with the definition of compactness, I think the problem is I don't know what the definition of "choose" means, but I have a feeling that I don't have the background to understand it.

Comment: @Seth The axiom of choice isn't really about "choosing" in the sense of choosing what to eat for dinner. What is says is that given any collection of disjoint, nonempty sets, there exists a set consisting of exactly one element from each of them. Making use of the axiom is construed as "choosing" such a set.

Comment: @Matt According to you, does the proposed direct proof use the axiom of choice ?

Comment: @user996987 not explicitly. I have no problem with the proof, it answers the question in my opinion, I was just commenting on a comment. Seth's answer to your first question is good too. It's a sequence, it's indexed by the positive Integers, which is a well ordered set.

Comment: @Matt Actually I really don't see how to create the sequence B_k of balls of radius 1/k (various centres) with infinitely many elements without the axiom of choice. It is the first step to create the Cauchy subsequence right ?

Comment: Choices are made at three stages: choosing a finite subcovering for each n, choosing a set from each such covering and choosing a point of the sequence from this set. The latter two do not need the axiom of choice because you can use the original ordering of the sequence to specify which element to choose, but I can't see how you can make the first choice without the axiom, or at least the axiom of countable choice.    More importantly, the answer only shows that every sequence has a Cauchy subsequence, it still remains to prove "directly" that that has a limit point

Comment: @David Are you sure we can use the original ordering of the sequence to choose a set from each sub covering ? These sets may intersect. Hence, for example, choosing the first which is reached by the sequence does not work, right?

Comment: By the way, I have no problem with the answer to the question, I just want to be sure what it relies on. And it looks like the proof by contradiction has the benefit not requiring AC.

Comment: @user996987 You're quite right. It's possible that two or more balls from the subcovering contain exactly the same points of the sequence and come "joint-first" among those that fit the requirements for the proof. Just use their intersection.

Comment: @David Yes you're right. With the intersection, by choosing the intersection it's working. One more detail: to ensure that the resulting subsequence is Cauchy, the successive choices of sets in the sub covering are not independent. So, it looks like we use something stronger than the axiom of choice...?

Comment: @user996987 Yes, each of those sets is dependent on the previous ones but, using the intersections if necessary, there's no choice involved (except of course that of choosing the  subcoverings in the first place). Even if there was we would only need the Axiom of Dependent Choice which is stronger than Countable Choice but weaker than the full Axiom of Choice....Still don't see how you get from Cauchy subsequence to convergent subsequence "directly"?

Comment: @David ok thanks. About the last step, to conclude from being Cauchy to being convergent, actually I do not see a direct proof for now.

Comment: To go from Cauchy to convergent you still need an extra lemma about decreasing families of closed sets of decreasing diameter e.g.

Comment: But I think (cannot check as I'm not near my books now) that any proof of compact implies seq. compact in a metric space will involve at least the axiom of countable or dependent choice. @AsafKaragila might know.